# Add string object to linkedlist in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to add string objects to a linked list but i keep getting an error when I try to return the list

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class StacksAndQueues {
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    private String[] words = {"goats", "cheese"};

    public StacksAndQueues() {}

    public String Add() {
        /**
           This method is used to load an array of string objects
           into a linked list
        */
        int x;
        for (x=0; x < words.length; x++) {
            list.add(x, words[x]);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return the list from your `Add()` method then you will need to change the *signature* of the method.

```
public LinkedList<String> Add () {
    /**
     This method is used to load an array of string objects
     into a linked list
    */
    int x;
    for (x=0; x < words.length; x++) {
        list.add(x, words[x]);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are trying to return list while return type is given as String, change return type to List and it will work.